# Long process, binding update and UI frozen

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, dispatcher

My WPF/C# program use different methods called within a specifc sequence.
Each method are bound to the UI, displaying some data after a long process.
I'm using a dispatcher cause the called methods are in another thread.
I also would like to execute this process without freezing the UI, being able to cancel the process and freely displace the window for example.

My problem is that the UI is not updated at all (progress bar, calculation step) and the cancel button is not operating till the calculation ends.
In fact, o don't knwo how to cancel immediately the general sequence even if the pending long process is not finished.

I'm not 100% sure to use the correct way, does anyone have a better solution or any advice ?

ex.

```
   public void CalculationCommand()
   {
        var bkw = new BackgroundWorker()
        bkw.DoWork += Work;
        bkw.RunWorkerAsync(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher);
   }

   public void Work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
        var dispatcher = e.Argument as Dispatcher;
        var dispatcherPriority = DispatcherPriority.Background;
        Action action;

        action = () =>
        {
            UpdateStatut(StatutsInformation.Pending);
        };
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, dispatcherPriority);

        ViewModel1 viewModel1 = null;
        action = () =>
        {
            UpdateProgress(10, "Sampling calculations");
            viewModel1 = Application.GetEchantillonnage();//Long process
        };
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, dispatcherPriority);

        List<double> lengthList = null;
        action = () =>
        {
            UpdateProgress(20, "Length calculations");
            lengthList = AlgorithmLibrary.LengthCalculations(viewModel1);//Long process
        };
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, dispatcherPriority);

        ViewModel2 viewModel2 = null;
        action = () =>
        {
            UpdateProgress(30, "Engine calculations");
            viewModel2 = Application.GetEngine();//Long process
            AlgorithmLibrary.EngineCalculations(viewModel2);//Long process
            var FilteredLength = AlgorithmLibrary.LengthFilter(lengthList);//Long process
        };            dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, dispatcherPriority);

        ///... Others actions executed incrementing the progress value to 100%

        action = () =>
        {
            UpdateStatut(StatutsInformation.Finished);
        };
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, dispatcherPriority);
    }

private void UpdateStatut(StatutsInformation statutInformation)
{
    ViewModelLoading.StatutInformation = statutInformation;
}

private void UpdateProgress(int value, string label)
{
    ViewModelLoading.Progress = value;
    ViewModelLoading.Step = label;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the method `Work` you are executing on a background thread.  Every time you call `dispatcher.BeginInvoke` the *action* you pass to this method will be executed on ***the UI thread***.  See what you're doing now?  Look at this code again

```
// Here, we are on a background thread
action = () =>
{
    // This action is NOT executing yet!  We are just defining it.
    UpdateProgress(10, "Sampling calculations");
    // This is going to execute on the thread that executes this action!
    viewModel1 = Application.GetEchantillonnage();//Long process
};
// here, we are still on the background thread, but we are telling the
// dispatcher to marshall the action onto the UI thread to execute it!
dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, dispatcherPriority);
```

You're doing your long-running work on the UI thread :/

The solution is easy, though.  Simply pull your work out and keep it in the background thread.  Here's the same code, but working as expected (unless other issues arise in your code)

```
action = () => UpdateProgress(10, "Sampling calculations");    
dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action, dispatcherPriority);
viewModel1 = Application.GetEchantillonnage();//Long process
```

Comment: The problem here is that the call of "viewModel1 = Application.GetEchantillonnage()" give an error : "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it "

Comment: @midget you're doing something in that `GetEchantillonnage` method that is touching the UI.  I have no idea what or why, but you need to not do that.  If `GetEchantillonnage` needs something from the UI, then **get that information first** while you are still in the UI thread.  Then refactor this method so that it takes this information when you call it, and move the entire thing out of the Application object.

Comment: The important part of the MVVM pattern is to ***separate business logic from the UI***.  If you do that, then you have no problems.  But you're still mixing them together here (`Application` does not have a native `GetEchantillonnage` method--you put it there).  Refactor to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code keeps breaking into the background thread to do long-running tasks on the UI thread. Dispatcher.BeginInvoke marshals the delegate back to the UI thread.

Try this:

```
   private void RunOnUI(Action uiAction, DispatcherPriority dispatcherPriority = DispatcherPriority.Background)
   {
        dispatcher.BeginInvoke(uiAction, dispatcherPriority);
   }

   public void Work(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
   {
        var dispatcher = e.Argument as Dispatcher;
        var dispatcherPriority = DispatcherPriority.Background;
        Action action;

    runOnUI(() =>
    {
        UpdateStatut(StatutsInformation.Pending);
    });

    ViewModel1 viewModel1 = null;
    RunOnUI(() =>
    {
        UpdateProgress(10, "Sampling calculations");
    });
    viewModel1 = Application.GetEchantillonnage();//Long process

    List<double> lengthList = null;
    RunOnUI(() =>
    {
        UpdateProgress(20, "Length calculations");            
    });
    lengthList = AlgorithmLibrary.LengthCalculations(viewModel1);//Long process        

    ViewModel2 viewModel2 = null;
    RunOnUI(() =>
    {
        UpdateProgress(30, "Engine calculations");
    };
        viewModel2 = Application.GetEngine();//Long process
        AlgorithmLibrary.EngineCalculations(viewModel2);//Long process
        var FilteredLength = AlgorithmLibrary.LengthFilter(lengthList);//Long process

    ///... Others actions executed incrementing the progress value to 100%

    RunOnUI(() =>
    {
        UpdateStatut(StatutsInformation.Finished);
    });
}
```